# Jquery: swaping containers inside a container

Tags: jquery, containers

Still learning jquery. I wanted to swap the title and image inside their parent divs. Any ideas? Thanks much!

```
<div id="main">
<div class="image">IMAGE</div>
<div class="title">TITLE</div>
</div>

<div id="main">
<div class="image">IMAGE</div>
<div class="title">TITLE</div>
</div>

<div id="main">
<div class="image">IMAGE</div>
<div class="title">TITLE</div>
</div>

--------------------------------------------

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#main div").each(function(){
  $("#main").append($('.image'));

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: First off, IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: change `id="main"` to `class="main"`.  Also `$("#main div")` is wrong and change it as `$("div #main")`

Comment: can't make the class unique..I have changed the ID to class and the image div is now added 3 times..thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/YzXye/

Also, you should not multiple elements with same ID's.

**JS:-**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".main").each(function () {
        $(this).append($(this).find('.image'));

    });
});
```

**HTML:-**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="image">IMAGE</div>
    <div class="title">TITLE</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="image">IMAGE</div>
    <div class="title">TITLE</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="image">IMAGE</div>
    <div class="title">TITLE</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert `id` to `class` as `id` must be `unique` and try this like,

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="image">IMAGE</div>
    <div class="title">TITLE</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="image">IMAGE</div>
    <div class="title">TITLE</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="image">IMAGE</div>
    <div class="title">TITLE</div>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".main").each(function(){
       $image= $(this).find('.image');
       $clone=$image.clone();
       $image.remove();
       $(this).append($clone);
   });
});
```

**Or**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".main").each(function () {
        $(this).find('div.title').after($(this).find('div.image'));
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3K89/) and [Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3K89/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Once you fix your ID/class issue, here's a short solution:

```
$(".main").each(function () {
    $(this).find('div:eq(1)').after($(this).find('div:eq(0)'));
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/DxZgU/1)**